# Firebase Bucket Download File taking a lot of time

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm developing an app using Firebase as BaaS.

I'm having time problems when I'm uploading an image (with 90KB or less) and triggering a Cloud Function.

My trigger starts when upload ends:

```
exports.uploadControl = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((req, res) => {
    uploadControl.handler(req, res);
    return 0;
});
```

And, inside uploadControl, i have:

```
return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
    console.log('1. mkDirp - OK!');
    console.log('2. Download starts...');
    return bucket.file(filePath).download();
}).then((content) => {
    console.log('3. Download ends');
    return 0;
});
```

This code works fine, but the problem is the time spent between step 2 and 3...
It takes 24 sec or more.

How to solve this? Is there any code problem? Or is there a Firebase setting to solve it?

Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things wrong here:

1. The onFinalize() callback doesn't receive `res` and `req` objects like HTTP triggers do.  It receives object metadata as the first argument.  [Read the documentation for details.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events)
2. background triggers like this one [must return a promise when all the work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Otherwise Cloud Functions will shut down the work prematurely, as it has no idea when it's finished.  If you want to kick off all that work from another function, it should be returning that promise.

-

```
exports.uploadControl = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(object => {
    return uploadControl.handler(object);
});
```

Comment: Tks for your answer. Both problems was solved. Despite this, the time problem still happens. The code works to download the file, but the time spent is big yet (21 sec). Do you have any other tip?

Comment: it's not necessary. It really worked! Change to return a promise solve the o problem. Tks for your help!